# Azure APIM and function app - backend authentication

Tags: azure-functions, authorization, azure-api-management

We have a couple of function app APIs exposed to clients using the APIM. We are currently testing the authentication process, where clients will utilize a subscription key to access the APIM gateway. The backend authorization will then be handled either through APIM authorization with AAD or with a managed.

We have configured the Authorization (AAD - client credentials) following the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authorizations-how-to-azure-ad),
policy used

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <get-authorization-context provider-id="aad2" authorization-id="aad2" context-variable-name="auth-context" identity-type="managed" ignore-error="false" />
    <set-header name="authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@("Bearer " + ((Authorization)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("auth-context"))?.AccessToken)</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="apikey" exists-action="delete" />
    <set-header name="x-functions-key" exists-action="delete" />
</inbound>
```

And configured managed identity authentication following the [link](https://www.mikaelsand.se/2021/09/secure-communication-with-apim-and-functions-using-managed-identity/)

```
<base />
    <authentication-managed-identity resource="xxxx-xxx-4xxb-xxx-xxxxxxx" output-token-variable-name="msi-access-token" ignore-error="false" />
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["msi-access-token"])</value>
    </set-header>
```

In both scenarios, the trace shows a token is passed with the header and the result is successful. However, I am unsure if the "x-functions-key" in the header is what makes it work. I attempted to remove it using the policy , but it remains. If I remove it from the function app, a 401 unauthorized error occurs.

How can we confirm which one is making it work? Can we remove "x-functions-key" from the header or is it a mandatory value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am unsure if the "x-functions-key" in the header is what makes it work

Yes, actually **x-functions-key** helps the function to work if your function is created with Authorization level **Functions** and **Admin**. But if you have created your function with **Anonymous** Authorization level, then you don't need to pass **x-functions-key** while accessing the function.

> How can we confirm which one is making it work?

You can verify the function without adding `get-authorization-context` in your policy, it will give you expected result. So, **x-functions-key** is making the function work whereas **get-authorization-context** is adding extra level of security to your API.

> Can we remove "x-functions-key" from the header or is it a mandatory value?

AFAIK, you can't delete **x-functions-key**, as it's automatically getting added in backend. I have tried to add `<set-header name="x-functions-key" exists-action="delete" />` in the backend policy but it didn't allow me add.

Finally, I deleted it from the function app and tested my functions, one having **Anonymous** authentication and the other one having **Function** authentication.

**Result:**
*Anonymous authenticated function-*

[image]

*Function authenticated function-*

[image]

Hence, **x-functions-key** is making function work in case of **Function** and **Admin** authentication level function.